# Change flights in Copenhagen in 1 hour with checked baggage?

Tags: short-connections, copenhagen

I booked two flights via Copenhagen, the first one (Norwegian) arriving there at 11:05 and the next (Ryanair) departing at 12:00.

I have checked baggage and I booked these flights separately, directly at Norwegian and Ryanair pages. (this means that the airport staff won't transfer my baggage to the next airplane, right?)

Is it possible to make such a transfer on time, or should I book another, earlier flight while there's still time?

Or is it possible to do something like calling to the airport and make sure they would transfer my baggage automatically?

Comment: You should add details about the origin of the first flight and the destination of the latter. If any of them are outside the Schengen area you'll additionally have to go through passport control, which will add even more time. Also consider that scheduled landing time is not necessarily actual landing time...

Comment: @jcaron they are both in Schengen area. From Prague and to Kaunas. I dont think there will be much of a variation in landing time

Comment: totally impossible unfortunately!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Baggage cannot be transferred automatically because neither Norwegian nor Ryanair will accept the legal responsibility that comes with forwarding and accepting interline baggage.

If you look at [Ryanair's website](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Online-check-in-airport-bag-drop-desks#0-1), Ryanair closes the bag drop forty minutes before departure.

I think it is quite unlikely that you will be able to deplane, retrieve your baggage, and make it to a check in desk in under twenty minutes of the scheduled landing.

Therefore I think it is highly unlikely that this connection will succeed (probably less than five percent chance). I would advise you to rebook with a much greater margin of error (probably at least two hours).

Comment: Highly unlikely indeed. My experience with arriving in Copenhagen (my home airport) is that it usually takes about 15-20 minutes _after_ I reach the baggage claim myself before the belt actually starts moving. And there's at least 5 minutes walk from the baggage reclaim (in terminal 3 for all international arrivals) to Ryanair's check-in desks (in terminal 2).

Comment: And Ryanair will just LOVE you to miss the bag drop of and therefore your flight, as they can then sell you anther flight at a much higher cost on the day!

Comment: @IanRingrose Ryanair will also love to reschedule.